# Implication of "gradually pulled\moved\pushed" in high school Newtonian physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

In some of the physics problem I've been going over, the phrase "gradually pulled/moved/pushed" is coming up again. I can not understand what the implication of this is. Here is an example problem where it comes,

> In the setup shown, a block is placed on a frictionless floor, the cord and pulleys are ideal and each spring has stifness $k$. The block is pulled away from the wall. How far will the block shift, while the pulling force is increased gradually from zero to a value $F$?
>
> [image]

My concern what does the meaning of "gradual" in this case imply? Does the word play any vital role?

**To be clear, I am not interested in the solution of above the problem, but rather what "gradually pulled" means in this post**

Comment: Oof you gave up all your rep for this? Seems like you really want an answer haha

Comment: I'd recommend adding in the two questions exactly

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Cool, I was afraid adding in the 2 ques might get this post closed as homework.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Haha yes I don't really care about reputation...By the way I edited and have uploaded the link towards the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question now. I think you've misunderstood why your previous questions got closed. It is not because you put a problem in itself, but it doesn't isolate your issue to something specific. This question, for example, is good, because you give something which is concrete and can be simply answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this remark is probably to avoid dealing with complications that arise if you were to not gradually exert a force. For instance, in real life if you yank on a box attached to a spring (the spring is attached to some wall as in your picture) and then hold the box with the same force you yanked it with, the spring will not just extend: it will wiggle and wobble and probably have some sort of wave motion going through it. In other words, the situation becomes more complicated. To avoid this potentially complicated spring behavior, we gradually increase the force exerted on the box.

It is the same general idea as the following. In some electricity and magnetism problems, we talk about "moving a charge such that the charge does not accelerate". We do not want the charge to accelerate because accelerating charges can introduce the complication of radiation.

Comment: This is the right answer provided the context. The context only came bit later, so my answer got invalidated in the process of it.

Comment: Ah I see! @TrystwithFreedom

Comment: Also, the same is true when we are said to "gently raise" an object above ground to calculate potential energy at $h$.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to yank the block with a force F from the get go, since the springs are slack in the beginning, this impulse/work would translate into kinetic energy of the block. When the block reaches the distance where the spring forces equals F, which is the distance the question is really asking about, the block would slide on past this distance because of the kinetic energy, refuting the point of the question (the way it is formulated).

Comment: Ok due to Inertia right?

Comment: The spring forces will be less than F until the block  reaches the distance the question is asking about, so if you use a force F from the start there will be a net force doing positive work on the block all the way until it reaches that distance - this work means the block gains kinetic energy and keeps on sliding past it. If instead the block is moved gradually in such a way that the force applied equals the force from the springs at all times, but allowing for a negligible positive velocity so that it actually moves, the box will "stop" and the question makes sence as formulated

Comment: (Sure, due to intertia)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to silly goose answer, in case we had friction on the ground, this would have another implication. The block won't move till the force applied exceeds a threashhold; the static friction limit.

Have a look on [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html) for more info.

Comment: Isn't the floor frictionless?

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce this system to mass and one spring , spring constant K . hence the energy of this system is:

$$E=\frac 12 M\,v^2=\frac 12 K\,x^2+F\,x$$

where M is the block mass.

if the force is increase gradually, this means that the velocity is neglected $~ v\mapsto 0~$ , so you obtain the distance of the block from the energy equation $~(x=\frac{2\,F}{K}~$).